# Visual Studio 2008 Properties Window SLOW

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Even after all the hotfixes and updates that are supposed to fix this, my properties window in Visual Studio 2008 is still SLOW!  What happens is a click on a table cell or something similar in the web editor, and regardless of the size of the page I'm working on, it takes a second or two for the properties window to show the properties for the selected item.

The most annoying thing about it is sometimes I'll click a cell, select a property and start typing, but it's still stuck on the wrong (unselected) item, so it ends up putting what I'm typing in the wrong place, and then it disappears once the proper item is selected.

Like I said, I'm running with all available hotfixes and service packs.  Anyone run into this and had any luck fixing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured out the problem I was having - I turned off the startup page, and disabled the startup page refresh option (where it checks for latest content every 60 minutes or whatever), so that now when I load the environment, it just shows a blank page.

I have no idea why this would relate to the amount of time it takes an item selected in the HTML designer to appear in the properties window, but evidently the two things are connected.

Comment: Could you please post the step-by-step instruction on how to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turn off all animation.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't work - even with animation off, the property page is slow to switch to the new selected object.  For instance, if you are inside a table and it is showing the  properties, when you hit "Escape" so that the parent table is selected, it takes 2-3 seconds for the properties of the parent table to appear.